# Matlab: First Non-zero element of each row or column

Tags: matlab, matrix, sparse-matrix, sparse-array

For example,

```
A = [ -1   0  -2   0   0
   2   8   0   1   0
   0   0   3   0  -2
   0  -3   2   0   0
   1   2   0   0  -4];
```

how can I get a vector of the first nonzero elements of each row?

Comment: what would you expect if there is an "all zeros" row?

Answer (score 17):

You can use `max`:

```
>> [sel, c] = max( A ~=0, [], 2 );
```

Rows for which `sel` equalse zero - are all zeros and the corresponding column in `c` should be ignored.

Result:

```
>> [sel c]= max( A~=0, [], 2 )

sel =
 1
 1
 1
 1
 1
c =
 1
 1
 3
 2
 1
```

In order to find the first non-zero row index (for each column) you just need to apply `max` on the first dimension:

```
>> [sel r] = max( A~=0, [], 1 );
```

Comment: This is a better solution as `find` can explode when working larger matrices.

Comment: how do I find the values rather than the indices?

Answer (score 9):

Here is a solution based on [accumarray](http://www.mathworks.ch/ch/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html) that will work even if a row is all zeros.

```
A = [ -1   0  -2   0   0
   2   8   0   1   0
   0   0   3   0  -2
   0  -3   2   0   0
   1   2   0   0  -4];

[r,c] = find(A);

%# for every row, take the minimum column index and put NaN if none is found
firstIndex = accumarray(r,c,[size(A,1),1],@min,NaN);
```

Comment: FYI, you may need `accumarray(r,c,[size(A,1),1],@min,NaN)` because `accumarray` requires the size be specified as `[M 1]` (at least in my version of MATLAB)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by executing [find](http://www.mathworks.com.au/help/matlab/ref/find.html) function for each row as follows:

```
A = [ -1   0  -2   0   0
   2   8   0   1   0
   0   0   3   0  -2
   0  -3   2   0   0
   1   2   0   0  -4];

% make cell of rows
cellOfRows = num2cell(A, 2);

% apply find function for each row
indexOfFirstNonZeroValues = cellfun(@(row) find(row, 1, 'first'), cellOfRows);


indexOfFirstNonZeroValues =

     1
     1
     3
     2
     1
```

Comment: this will fail if there is a row of all zeros.