# find the first and last non zero number in a matrix in matlab

Tags: matrix, find

i have a matirx: new_mat= [ 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0; 0 0 0 2 6 10 0 0 0 ; 0 0 3 7 11 15 19 0 0; 0 4 8 12 16 20 24 28 0; 0 14 18 22 26 0 0 0 0 ; 0 0 0 0 0 30 34 38 0] i want the first and last non zero number of each row in the matrix as first= 1; 2; 3; 4;14; 30] and last=[1; 10; 19; 28; 26; 38];
how do i get these values? I can use loops or even the find function.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Matlab: First Non-zero element of each row or column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19624794/matlab-first-non-zero-element-of-each-row-or-column)

Comment: i did try it, but that code gives the index i just need the numbers that's the first non-zero!

Comment: Then I would suggest [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19624967/1377097) and rather than returning the results of `find(...)`, return the results of `row(find(...))`. Also note the comment there: if there is a possibility that your rows might have all zeros, you'll need to set `UniformOutput` to `false`.